# How to edit files in certain folders - excluding all other folders

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on this script and I am trying to make this read a certain Folder

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern="
Set "Replace="

@For %%G In ('dir /b /a-d "Quills"') Do (

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "*.txt"') DO (
    Set "File=%%~na"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!%%~xa"
  )
)
```

I have tried multiple setting but nothing seems to work 
I added this  `@For %%G In ('dir /b /a-d "Quills"') Do (` 
I added this `Set "Source="` 
I added this `@For %%G In (Quills) Do (` 
I added this `FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "Quill\*.txt"') DO (`

Quills is the Folder Name I want it to read, and I have many Sub folders and Quill is found in many places Any Help will be awesome

I have many folders with many different names, and I have different folders I edit files in

```
example:
main folder
--- Folder 1
------Quills
------Folder 1
------Folder 2
main folder 2
--- Folder 1
------Quills
------Folder 1
------Folder 2
```

Quill is located in many different Sub Folders, and inside of every folder I have many txt files, what I do is I use the script to edit the file name, I remove certain characters  from the file name, for example `upper_case.txt`, here I would use the `Search` to find all`_`and `Replace` it with a `space`, like this `upper case.txt`, but I only want the script to do this to the files found inside the Quills Folders

OK, guys thanks to `Gerhard` I was able to find the problem with my original script

I will leave my fixed original script here for anyone that might need it

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=What to search for"
Set "Replace=What to replace it with"

FOR /R %%a IN ("Folder Name\*.txt") DO (
    Set "File=%%~na"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!%%~xa"
)
```

Thank you

Comment: The outer loop contains a 'command' too, just like the inner, _(nested)_, one. It should therefore also be a `For /F` loop! However, it appears to be only identifying a file in the current directory with the exact case insensitive name "Quills", which I'm going to assume is not what you wanted to do. How about you [edit] your question to inform us what you intended the script to do. That would enable us to understand where you are going wrong with it.

Comment: If you open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, you should see all of its options. Among those there is explained the `/A` _(attribute)_, and in particular the `D` attribut and the reverse prefix. That should help you with that outer `For /F` loop, as should understanding that each line from that 'command' will be returned as `%%G`. You may therefore need to learn where in your inner loop to insert that `%%G` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that `Quills` is a single Directory and you want to recursively search files in the root and subfolders of it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "search=str_to_search"
set "replace=to_replace"
for /R %%i in ("Quills\*.txt") do (
    set "fname=%%~nxi"
    if "!fname:%search%=%search%!" == "!fname!" ren "%%~fi" "!fname:%search%=%replace%!"
)
```

If however you have mulitple `Quills` directories in different sub Folders and want to do it for each of them:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "search=search_str"
set "replace=replace_str"
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b/s/a-d *.txt ^| findstr /i "Quills\\"') do (
    set "fname=%%~nxi"
    if "!fname:%search%=%search%!" == "!fname!" ren "%%~fi" "!fname:%search%=%replace%!"
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work, the Folder called Quills is located in a many different folders and Sun Folders, it is not a direct Main folder,  I do a Search for file names, I remove certain characters from i using the Search and Replace, the second script appears to be searching for something, but does not edit the files, since I have many folders with different names, and they all have similar characters, I am trying to target only folders with the name Quills, I will update my question a little better

Comment: My apologies. I had an `echo` in my second example for testing purpose. I updated it, please copy again and test.

Comment: -You know I just thought about that as I was logging back in, Echo doesn't let it read it, OK that fixed that, but it's editing every file in every folder, it it not focusing only on `Quills Folder`

Comment: This is where I fall into the problem, I can't make if to only look at Quills Folder

Comment: It will, but that depends if you want to recurse through subfolders of Quills?

Comment: Well yes the idea is that Quill folders are located in Sub folders, as I have added an example of the location of the folders, I have a main folder, then a sub folder, and on some the Quill is found right after the first Sub Folder, and some are found in a second Sub Folder, I have tried to use the second script but it's editing every folder found in the main folder, I really do appreciate the help, but it's not focusing only on that Quill folder, I have positions the Quill Folder in many different positions and still it edits every txt file in every folder

Comment: OK, so the First script you shared for some odd reason works, even with this missing `'dir /b/s/a-d` not sure why, but this finds only the Quills folders. in any location, your second script does not focus on Quill, it finds ever txt file, I did notice this between both scripts `for /R` and `for /f`

Comment: Thank you for the help, your script helped me find the problem with mine, I added the `for /R` and and added this `("Quill\*.txt")` and done

Comment: OK, I found that /R reads every folder and Subs - I over looked that - Now I know - once again Thank you

Comment: No problem. So if you run `for /?` from `cmd` you will see the differences between `/R` and `/F`.